Microsoft tenant to tenant migration: Error: MigrationCSVRowValidationException
enter link description hereI am migrating mailboxes from one MS365 tenant to another. I am following all the steps from this webpage "Cross-tenant mailbox migration - Microsoft 365 Enterprise | Microsoft Learn".  But now i am stuck. I performed the migration from the Exchange Admin site for one test mailbox and I get the error:
Error: MigrationCSVRowValidationException: The migration user type for 'zapped@zapped.nl' is not correct. Please ensure it has RecipientTypeDetails:MailUser.

When i check the details of the user with PowerShell I can see the RecipientTypeDetails are 'MailUser' for the useraccount in the target:

How to solve this? Where do I start?
Update (3/7/2024):
I got a reply from Microsoft that this could be explained by multiple causes and they advised me to contact their engineers through a support ticket.
I am going to contact MS support and if there is a solution to the problem i will provide an update.
Update (4/7/2024):
Microsoft support was unreachable
I found the answer though. See post below.

The microsoft support send me in a support loop, going from phonenumber to website and vice versa.
But i solved the problem thanks to Somitvsk. I misread and put the source emailadress in the csv file. This causes the above error.
See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-tenant-to-tenant-migration-error/ecc0a307-6c57-4b6c-ae81-6dc9027f34df?rtAction=1720096148343
